# How to resize images alongside buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

In my code, I managed to be able to resize buttons I had based on my window's size and it worked great, but the issue that I have is that those buttons have images inside of them. And when I resize the buttons, the images themselves Adjust fine in terms of alignment, but they don't get bigger alongside the buttons. So I was wondering how can I accomplish that. This code here is just one button to avoid clutter.

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = Tk()

Grid.rowconfigure(root,1,weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root,0,weight=1)

movie_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage( Image.open("clapperboard.png")  )

MyLabel_Movie = Button(root , bd = 4 , image = movie_img , bg = "#b00029" , activebackground = "#ff003b" ) 
MyLabel_Movie2 = Label(root , text= 'Movies' , font=('Orelega One','20' , 'italic underline') )
MyLabel_Movie2.grid( row = 0, column = 0, sticky="NSEW" )
MyLabel_Movie.grid( row = 1, column = 0, sticky="NSEW")

root.mainloop()
```

Edit:
I found a "fix" but it's not ideal.

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

Grid.rowconfigure(root,1,weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root,0,weight=1)

def resize_main(e):
    global movie_img,new_movie_img,resized_movie_img,Button_Movie

    movie_img = Image.open("clapperboard_og.png")
    resized_movie_img = movie_img.resize( (int(e.width/2.5), int(e.height/2.5)), Image.ANTIALIAS )
    new_movie_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage( resized_movie_img )
    Button_Movie.configure( image = new_movie_img )


movie_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage( Image.open("clapperboard_og.png")  )

Button_Movie = Button(root , bd = 4 , image = movie_img , bg = "#b00029" , activebackground = "#ff003b" ) 
MyLabel_Movie2 = Label(root , text= 'Movies' , font=('Orelega One','20' , 'italic underline') )
MyLabel_Movie2.grid( row = 0, column = 0, sticky="NSEW" )
Button_Movie.grid( row = 1, column = 0, sticky="NSEW")


root.mainloop()
```

It resizes the images inside the button but it's laggy when resizing the window. Is this the best tkinter can offer or is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with resizing an image in the button, we only need one button with one image in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think it's better to use Canvas because it offers to you many possibility . For example , you could make the image itself as a button that you could resize as you want  .

Comment: You're right Bryan I should've done that instead of putting 4 buttons here. I'll look into that Ayyoub, I didn't realize you can have Canvases clickable as buttons thanks.